# Spring Boot - block DB read on service method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions, synchronization, locking

I have the following scenario, on a Spring Boot application:
My service method reads a set of items from the DB where item.status = 'open'.
Then I will change the status of one of those items to 'closed' and do some actions.

Thing is, if multiple requests come to the server, too close (within milliseconds) parallel executions are started, and these parallel executions have access to an old state (where an item still is 'open' when it has actually been processed) causing processed items to be reprocessed which cannot happen.

I've tried using Isolation mode of the transaction to serialised but his does not solve the issue.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong or stuff I can try?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to look at optimistic/pessimistic locking concepts and choose what's suits you best.

If you're using `JPA` it already has [tools](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html) for [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Version.html).

If not then there is a little bit more manual work for optimistic lock and some database specific sugar for pessimistic (e.g. `SELECT...FOR UPDATE`)

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much for your input. So far I've ended up creating a DAO method (JpaRepository) that performs a PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock. It seems to work. I think this would be the least invasive option with the project I have at hands, and today, as implementing optimistic locking with Version is already planned for the future.